# Kubernetes gitconfig mounted as directory instead of file

Tags: azure, kubernetes, volumes

I have some helm charts in which I would like to mount the git config globally on each container.

In this case the home directory for each container is / path. When I would like to do it manually on the container I am getting following

`git config --global --add safe.directory "*" error: could not lock config file //.gitconfig: Permission denied`

Now I want to map my config map to the global .gitconfig file.

```
  set {
    name  = "git.sync.extraVolumeMounts[0].name"
    value = "git-config"
  }
  set {
    name  = "git.sync.extraVolumeMounts[0].mountPath"
    value = "/.gitconfig"
  }

  set {
    name  = "git.sync.extraVolumeMounts[0].subPath"
    value = ".gitconfig"
  }
```

With such config I am getting the .gitconfig as folder not the file

```
bitnami@airflow-web-7cdb6f5d6f-48mzh:/$ ls -la
total 84
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    4096 Dec  2 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    4096 Dec  2 12:20 ..
drwxrwsrwx   2 root bitnami 4096 Dec  2 12:20 .gitconfig
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    4096 Jul 30 11:21 bin
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there any environment variable instead I can set?

I tried to use system config but it does not work either as some folder structure is missing.

Comment: You're trying to modify a gitconfig that exists in a ConfigMap while it's mounted in a container? Don't think that's possible - you have to modify the ConfigMap using kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future, I was able to achieve that with the usage of the proper escaping

```
              {
                "name": "git.sync.extraVolumeMounts[0].mountPath",
                "type": null,
                "value": "/\\.gitconfig"
              },
              {
                "name": "git.sync.extraVolumeMounts[0].name",
                "type": null,
                "value": "git-config"
              },
              {
                "name": "git.sync.extraVolumeMounts[0].subPath",
                "type": null,
                "value": "gitconfig"
              },
```

This basically, creates a .gitconfig file and not a folder.

Setup is working fine.